# Using Atom editor in the Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, atom-editor, shared-directory

I have set up Ubuntu Vagrant box on my Mac. In the Ubuntu terminal I would like to type command `Atom foldername` (just like in Mac terminal) which would open Atom code editor that is installed on my Mac.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answer says that's not possible. what you can do is either configure a sync folder something like this

```
 config.vm.synced_folder "macfolder/", "/srv/vagrantfolder"
```

That basically will do the same as your vagrant folder, only you can add aditional folders. With that you are sharing folders so you can use your atom editor and your changes will be reflected on the ubuntu VM.

Or you can install atom on your ubuntu and forward the x server like this

```
  config.ssh.forward_x11 = true
```

Im no mac user so not sure if you need to install an X server on your mac. basic google search points me to this direction

http://www.xquartz.org/

That will give you the feeling you are using the atom editor in your mac. Only your mac is only "rendering" the editor

Hope it helps

Comment: If you choose to make a synced_folder, be forewarned. The initial sync is always from host to guest. Thus is you have files on your guest and make a synced_folder to a new directory on your host (e.g. MAC), vagrant reload will wipe the guest directory clean! Happened to me and others.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to call an application running on the host from the VM - they are separated environment. If you call `Atom x` from the VM ubuntu will run Atom from its system, it cannot make a call to your mac app.

Either use vi(m) if you run on CLI or start the GUI and install an IDE on your VM.

Another possibility is to use shared folder with vagrant so you edit your project files from your MAC and they are visible within the VM